# PHP+HTML: file not loaded from form

Tags: php, html, forms

In my form a user can choose to upload a file. So, here's the correspondent field in the form. here is the html code:

```
<p>
 <label>Allega fattura</label>
 <span class="field">
 <input type="file" name="allegato_fattura" id="allegato_fattura" value="Sfoglia..." />
</span>
```

and when the submit button is clicked, here we go:

```
...
    define("DIR_FATTURE","fatture/");
    $fatturaFileName;
    $addedFattura = false;

    if (file_exists($_FILES['allegato_fattura']['tmp_name']) || is_uploaded_file($_FILES['allegato_fattura']['tmp_name'])) {
        $addedFattura = true;
        $fatturaFileName = $_FILES['allegato_fattura']['name'];

        if (file_exists(DIR_FATTURE.$_FILES['allegato_fattura']['name'])){
            $fatturaFileName=time()."_".$_FILES['allegato_fattura']['name'];
            $_FILES['allegato_fattura']['name']=$fatturaFileName;
        }

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['allegato_fattura']['tmp_name'], DIR_FATTURE.$_FILES['allegato_fattura']['name']);
    }
```

and this does not work. I wrote the same files/script for other forms and they worked, I do not know why this does not: no file is loaded and the variable 
    $fatturaFileNale
remains null and so neither the name file is written in the database.
Obviously the directory "fatture" exists in the server in the correct path...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

```
<form name="item" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Oh god...I had completely forgotten about that...excuse-me and thank you from heart!

Comment: OK. Welcome... Because may times i also forget it and finally think of missing that....